# jQuery hover - mouseout event not working in IE8

Tags: jquery, html, internet-explorer-8, hover, mouseleave

I have two boxes on my screen, both with dynamically generated text. The first is a mad-libs type of paragraph where you can click on words on the bottom half of the screen and have them replace words in the top box. (They're linked by the 'data-id' attribute in the code here.) What I want is for the words in the bottom box to be underlined when I hover over them and the corresponding word in the top box to be bolded. The mouseenter handler for hover works just fine in all my browsers. But the mouseleave handler seems to be ignored in IE8, because words stay bolded and underlined in IE8.

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    function hoverIn () {
        var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
        var txt = $('.fullText span[data-id='+id+']').text();
        var vartxt = $(this).text();
        $('.fullText span[data-id='+id+']').html('<b>'+txt+'</b>');
        $(this).html('<u>'+vartxt+'</u>');
    } 
    function hoverOut () {
        var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
        var txt = $('.fullText span[data-id='+id+']').html();
        var newtxt1 = txt.replace(/<b>/gm, '');
        var newtxt = newtxt1.replace(/<\/b>/gm, '');
        var vtxt = $(this).html();
        var newvtxt1 = vtxt.replace(/<u>/gm, '');
        var newvtxt = newvtxt1.replace(/<\/u>/gm, '');
        $('.fullText span[data-id='+id+']').html(newtxt);
        $(this).html(newvtxt);
    }
    $('body').load( function(){
      $('#analyzed').addClass('analyzed');
     });
    $(".confWords span").bind('click', (function () {
      var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
      $('.fullText span[data-id='+id+']').text($(this).text());
    }));
    $(".confWords span").hover( hoverIn, hoverOut );

    // Disregard the next
    $("#reset").bind('click', (function() {
      $('.orig').trigger('click');
    }));
    $("#edit").bind('click', (function() {
      history.back(-1);
    }));
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than relying on .hover() try delegating to mouseenter and mouseleave specifically.

```
$('.confWords span').live('mouseenter mouseleave', function(event) {
    if (event.type == 'mousenter') {
        hoverIn();
    } else if (event.type == 'mouseleave') {
        hoverOut();
    }
});
```

You may also need to add `event.stopPropagation();` to prevent the event from trickling back up the DOM after the hover as follows:

```
$('.confWords span').live('mouseenter mouseleave', function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();

    if (event.type == 'mousenter') {
        hoverIn();
    } else if (event.type == 'mouseleave') {
        hoverOut();
    }
});
```